# Multiple user tiers Google+ API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, google-api, google-oauth, google-plus

The question is fairly simple, but I've yet to find an answer to it.  Is it possible to use Google+ API in an asp.net-mvc web app that requires multiple tiers of users?

For example, this app basically needs three sets of users and permissions associated with each: Admins, Members, Guests.  Mind you, I've never handled user authentication of any type before, so I'm happy to hear suggestions for other frameworks if you think those would be better.

Comment: how google api usage is related to user's tiers?

Comment: I'm not really sure, that's the problem.  I'm just trying to figure out if it is even possible before I invest a lot of time into learning the API.

Answer (score 0):

I think its going to be very hard for you to get three sets of user credentials in a single app.

For you to be able to authenticate as user one your going to need user one to authenticate your application then you will have access to that users data.   If you need access to user twos data your going to have to have that user authenticate your application.   If you need access to both users the same time its going to be very hard for you to get this access unless they are both using the same computer together.

While it is possible to get a refresh token for user one returned which you could store on your server some place and then use that to access user ones data when user two is on their machine.  This becomes a gray area as you are responsible of holding user ones data private especially from user two.

as for your different leaves of users thats just part of your system it should just be a matter of strong the users ids associated with their role within the system.

None of this has anything to do with doing this in .net. You could probably work it all out using the .net client library.  [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)